# Convert to DTO list property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following DTO:

```
public class QuestionGroupDTO : IBaseDTO
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Services.Forms.Models.RelationForm_QuestionGroupDTO> RelationForms_QuestionGroups { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<RelationQuestionGroup_QuestionDTO> RelationQuestionGroups_Questions { get; set; }
}
```

I have problem with the `RelationQuestionGroups_Questions` while converting.

Here Is how my `RelationQuestionGroup_QuestionDTO` looks like

```
public class RelationQuestionGroup_QuestionDTO
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid QuestionGroupId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid QuestionId { get; set; }

    public virtual QuestionGroupDTO QuestionGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionDTO Question { get; set; }
}
```

Here Is how I convert:

```
public static QuestionGroupDTO ToDTO(this QuestionGroup src)
{
    var dto = new QuestionGroupDTO
    {
        Id = src.Id,
        Header = src.Header,
        Description = src.Description,
        RelationQuestionGroups_Questions = src.RelationQuestionGroups_Questions.ToList()
    };
    return dto;
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to just assign It and make a list of It, but I got a casting error here. I'm not sure how to do this.

I get the following error:

> Cannot implicity convert type Generic List to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerble

Comment: _"a casting error"_ - which one? What did your research show for it? You can't implicitly convert your RelationQuestionGroups_Question entity to a RelationQuestionGroups_QuestionDTO, you need to map it just like you map the QuestionGroupDTO.

Comment: I am sure that error says that you cannot implicitly cast IEnumerable<RelationQuestionGroups_Questions> to IEnumerable<RelationQuestionGroups_QuestionsDTO>

Comment: @CodeCaster: But how do I map this and add this mapped object to the QuestionGroupDTO?

Comment: No, you're trying to assign a `List<Entity>` to `List<Dto>`. You can't do that. You need to `.Select(Map).ToList()`, where `Map` is a method like `RelationQuestionGroups_QuestionDTO Map(RelationQuestionGroups_Question entity)`.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Can you show me a example?

Answer (score 2):

You're having a great start at mapping, but at `RelationQuestionGroups_Questions = src.RelationQuestionGroups_Questions.ToList()`, you're trying to assign a `List<Entity>` to `List<Dto>`. You can't do that.

You need to map any non-primitive properties as well. You can do that like this:

```
public static QuestionGroupDTO ToDTO(this QuestionGroup src)
{
    var dto = new QuestionGroupDTO
    {
        // ...
        RelationQuestionGroups_Questions = src.RelationQuestionGroups_Questions
                                              .Select(ToDTO)
                                              .ToList()
    };
    return dto;
}
```

Then you add a method to map `RelationQuestionGroups_Question` to `RelationQuestionGroups_QuestionDTO`:

```
public RelationQuestionGroups_QuestionDTO ToDTO(RelationQuestionGroups_Question entity)
{
    return new RelationQuestionGroups_QuestionDTO
    {
        Order = entity.Order,
        // ...
    };
}
```

And then you'll go look at AutoMapper to automate this.

Comment: And I have to do this with the QuestionDTO(inside RelationQuestionGroups_QuestionDTO) too?

Comment: @Bryan yes, you need to map any non-primitive (or rather, any type for which no implicit conversion to the target type exists) as well.

Comment: Okey. But how do I add the mapped QuestionDTO to RelationQuestionGroups_Questions? You use .Select(ToDTO) for the RelationQuestionGroups. But how about QuestionDTO? Should I call It from inside ToDTO?

Comment: Yes, so you create a method `public QuestionDTO ToDTO(Question entity) { return new QuestionDTO { ... } }` and so on. Or use AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to map **RelationQuestionGroups_Questions** to **RelationQuestionGroup_QuestionDTO**.

```
public static QuestionGroupDTO ToDTO(this QuestionGroup src)
{
    var dto = new QuestionGroupDTO
    {
        Id = src.Id,
        Header = src.Header,
        Description = src.Description,
        RelationQuestionGroups_Questions = src.RelationQuestionGroups_Questions.Select(rq => new RelationQuestionGroup_QuestionDTO
            {
                Order = rq.Order,
                QuestionGroupId = rq.QuestionGroupId,
                QuestionId = rq.QuestionId
            }).ToList()
        };
    return dto;
}
```

Comment: What about the virtual QuestionDTO inside RelationQuestionGroups?

Comment: You should map it also, Question = new QuestionDTO {  ID = rq.Question.ID ... }